# Integrationtest of scrapy pipeline returning deferred

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, twisted, nose

Is it possible to create a integration test of a scrapy-pipeline? I can't figure out how to do this. In particular I am trying to write a test for the FilesPipeline and I also want it to persist my mocked response to Amazon S3.

Here is my test:

```
def _mocked_download_func(request, info):
    return Response(url=response.url, status=200, body="test", request=request)

class FilesPipelineTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.settings = get_project_settings()
        crawler = Crawler(self.settings)
        crawler.configure()
        self.pipeline = FilesPipeline.from_crawler(crawler)
        self.pipeline.open_spider(None)
        self.pipeline.download_func = _mocked_download_func

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def test_file_should_be_directly_available_from_s3_when_processed(self):
        item = CrawlResult()
        item['id'] = "test"
        item['file_urls'] = ['http://localhost/test']
        result = yield self.pipeline.process_item(item, None)
        self.assertEquals(result['files'][0]['path'], "full/002338a87aab86c6b37ffa22100504ad1262f21b")
```

I always run into the following error:

```
DirtyReactorAggregateError: Reactor was unclean.
```

How do I create a proper test using twisted and scrapy?

Answer (score 2):

Up do now I did my pipeline tests without the call to `from_crawler`, so they are not ideal, because they do not test the functionality of `from_crawler`, but they work.

I do them by using an empty `Spider` instance:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
# some other imports for my own stuff and standard libs

@pytest.fixture
def mqtt_client():
    client = mock.Mock()

    return client

def test_mqtt_pipeline_does_return_item_after_process(mqtt_client):
    spider = Spider(name='spider')
    pipeline = MqttOutputPipeline(mqtt_client, 'dummy-namespace')

    item = BasicItem()
    item['url'] = 'http://example.com/'
    item['source'] = 'dummy source'

    ret = pipeline.process_item(item, spider)

    assert ret is not None
```

(in fact, I forgot to call `open_spider()`)

You can also have a look at how scrapy itself does the testing of pipelines, [e.g. for `MediaPipeline`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/tests/test_pipeline_media.py):

```
class BaseMediaPipelineTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    pipeline_class = MediaPipeline
    settings = None

    def setUp(self):
        self.spider = Spider('media.com')
        self.pipe = self.pipeline_class(download_func=_mocked_download_func,
                                    settings=Settings(self.settings))
        self.pipe.open_spider(self.spider)
        self.info = self.pipe.spiderinfo

    def test_default_media_to_download(self):
        request = Request('http://url')
        assert self.pipe.media_to_download(request, self.info) is None
```

You can also have a look through their other unit tests. For me, these are always good inspiration on how to unit test scrapy components.

If you want to test the `from_crawler` function, too, you could have a look on their `Middleware` tests. In these tests, they often use `from_crawler` to create middlewares, [e.g. for OffsiteMiddleware](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/fd27cde24d273e30f72f53f2711515403270838a/tests/test_spidermiddleware_offsite.py).

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from scrapy.utils.test import get_crawler

class TestOffsiteMiddleware(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        crawler = get_crawler(Spider)
        self.spider = crawler._create_spider(**self._get_spiderargs())
        self.mw = OffsiteMiddleware.from_crawler(crawler)
        self.mw.spider_opened(self.spider)
```

I assume the key component here is to call `get_crawler` from `scrapy.utils.test`. Seems they factored out some calls you need to do in order to have a testing environment.